# Apollo readQuery, get data from cache

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm trying to get data from Apollo cache. I know that data is there because in Apollo dev tools specified records are available.
In my react app I making a simple click and set Id which later passes to the query. Result from `client.readQuery(...)` is `null`. I'm spinning around because don't know why. I'm using code exactly the same way as in docs.

Here's a QUERY:

```
export const RECRUIT_QUERY = gql`
  query Recruit($id: ID!) {
    Recruit(_id: $id) {
      _id
      firstName
    }
  }
`;
```

Usage of apollo hooks in component:

```
const client = useApolloClient();
const recruit = client.readQuery({
  query: RECRUIT_QUERY,
  variables: { id: selectedId }
})
```

Configuration of apollo:

```
export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: concat(
    authMiddleware,
    new HttpLink({
      uri: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
    }),
  ),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

Here's apollo store preview:
[image]

Comment: insert `debugger` and check if cache really contains these entries (don't trust dev tool) ... there is a difference between query and normalized type entries ... you're looking for `readFragment` ... why not simply use `useQuery` with `cache-only` field policy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `readFragment` covers my expectation. previously I have tried this solution but wrongly, ex:

```
 client.readFragment({
   id: '4587d3c2-b3e7-4ade-8736-709dc69ad31b',
   fragment: RECRUIT_FRAGMENT,
 });
```

In fact Appollo store cound't find this record. Correct solution looks like this:

```
client.readFragment({
  id: 'Recruit:4587d3c2-b3e7-4ade-8736-709dc69ad31b',
  fragment: RECRUIT_FRAGMENT,
})
```

Comment: what if you only have the name and are looking for the id? I'm also always getting null

Comment: @DamianGreen in this case you may customize your key take a look at this official docs https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration#customizing-cache-ids